# How to perform multiple nested navigation actions at once

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I have an app where at a certain point, multiple different navigation actions from multiple layers of the navigation stack need to happen simultaneously. To explain the use case, when the user adds an item to their cart from the item display screen, the item display screen should be removed from the history, and the user should be put into the cart screen (so that while they're in the cart, if they hit the back button, they're taken back to the item list, rather than the item they just added to their cart).

The trouble is, there doesn't seem to be a way to do both of these actions simultaneously. They always happen sequentially and, if the push action happens before the pop action, the back animation (after hitting back from the cart screen) happens twice, which is jarring for the user.

Here's what my stacks look like:

```
-- Root Stack
  -- Tab Stack
    -- Shop Stack
      -- Item List Screen
      -- Item Screen # <-- Navigation happens here
      -- ...other screens
    -- ...other tabs
  -- Cart Screen
  -- ...other screens
```

Here's what the code looks like:

```js
navigation.navigate('cart_screen');
navigation.goBack();
```

**My question is, is there a way to force the animation to happen while the inactive stack is not visible? Or perhaps a way to make both of the animations happen at once?** This would be easy if both screens were in the same stack, but it seems to be much trickier when the separate actions are happening on different stacks.

Comment: Well asked. I'm in the same boat, wanting to navigate and go back at the same time, wishing the animations played at the same time. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @BrianDunn I haven't, unfortunately. I figured out a couple workarounds, but they're all varying degrees of bad and ultimately haven't fixed the issue. Still kicking the can on this one until I work out a better solution.